# how to change font size in tikz automata?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is my tikz code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata,}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5 cm, scale = 0.5, transform shape]

  \node[initial,state] (A)                                  {$q_0$};
  \node[state]         (B) [right of=A,node distance=3 cm]              {$q_1$};
  \node[state]         (C) [right of=B,node distance = 6.5 cm]              {$q_2$};
  \node[state]         (D) [below right of=B]       {$q_3$};
  \node[state]         (E) [below right of=D]                   {$q_5$};
  \node[state]         (F) [below left of=D]                {$q_4$};


  \path[->] (A) edge [above]            node [align=center]             {a} (B)
        (B) edge [loop above]       node [align=center]             {a} (B)
        edge [bend right,below]     node [align=center]         {b} (C)
        edge [left]             node [align=center]         {a} (D)
        (C) edge [loop above]       node [align=center]         {b} (C)
        edge [bend right,right]     node [above,align=center]       {a} (B)
        edge [right]            node [align=center]             {a} (D)
        (D) edge [bend left,right]      node [align=center]         {d} (E)
        edge [bend right,left]      node [pos=0.4,align=center]     {a} (F)
        (E) edge [bend left]        node [pos=0.2,align=center]     {c} (D)
        (F) edge [bend right,above]     node [pos=0.6,align=center]     {b} (D)
        edge [bend left]        node [pos=0.7,align=center]     {a} (A);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output is :

[image]

I want to increase the size of the font over edges. How do I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the option `font=\Large`, for instance, to increase the size.  If you apply this to the `tikzpicture` options than all text will be made to be of `\Large` size.  If you only want it to apply to the `edges` then you add this option o the `edge`, either manually on a per edge basis, of with:

```
\tikzset{every edge/.append style={font=\Large}}
```